# Can someone die from not sleeping?

Tags: sleep, brain

I know this sounds like a weird question, but is it possible for someone not sleeping to die? What are all the negative consequences of not sleeping for long periods of time? Do you have any tips for sleeping when your brain is so wired and you toss and turn all night, just not being able to sleep even though you really try?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?